# Одинаковое отображение сайта на всех устройствах

Tags: вёрстка

Я понимаю, что сейчас на оборот все уходят как можно дальше от этого, но а мне на оборот понадобилось чтобы сайт на всех устройствах выглядел одинаково.

Помню раньше когда открываешь сайт текст, картинки все было мелким и приходилось увеличивать сайт чтобы хоть что-то разглядеть, но зато сайт ужимался в размеры экрана.

Вот в 2018 мне понадобилось сделать так же:)

Нашел кастыльное решение, сделать минимальную ширину body 1900px
И вроде бы получил то что хотел, но появился горизонтальный скролл

Так вот можно ли сдалать тоже самое но, чтобы все влезало в экран?

Comment: Все сайты по умолчанию такие, ничего для этого делать не надо, просто не нужно добавлять meta viewport вовсе. Ну или как вариант прописать в нём ширину, как в ответе предлагают

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в мета тег вашу ширину, но не запрещайте масштабирование, чтобы можно было рассмотреть содержимое на малых устройствах. Например:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1900, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: мб есть еще какие то способы добиться желаемого эффекта + чтобы исчез нижний скролл?

Comment: Без кода сложно сказать, может быть у вас в верстке проблемы какие-то. Т к не понятно где вертикальный скролл, при каких условиях, какая ширина, какое устройство, какой браузер..